# Need to integrate my own custom logs(in html or txt format) with prometheus or Kibana( using fluentd)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kibana, prometheus, fluentd

I have configured a script that fetch the GCP, Audit log and ssh logs from my cluster environment.

The data is stored as `html/txt` file format.

Now I want to fetch  these logs files by Prometheus or by Kibana UI (using EFK Stack) and need to display the same in Kibana or Prometheus UI.

Please let me know whether this is possible.